# Can't open my command line c++ app

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-terminal, programming

Well, i was making a c++ command line app for my game engine in arch linux. But i am on different computer now and it just can't run it. It can compile, but can't run.

https://pasteboard.co/IqyLM6i.png

as you can see in the image, when i run my app it stucks. Normally it should be generate a key for specific reasons but it is not. Is this my mistake or a bug?

I don't want to share my code but i'll share first part of program.
here is,

https://pastebin.com/Tqvau100

## 1

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first, I think that "*can't run*" isn't correct, because you can run it - you can see at your screenshot, that it runs (there is no *prompt line* after you start program) and the process is on.

Second, I think, that it can't be *Elementary Os* or *Pantheon* depended bug, so check your code carefully. You can try debuging. For example simple *cout*-debuging. Try insert some output in the begining of the main function to be sure, that it runs.

Third, I see, that it takes 100% of CPU, as htop says, and it just can be an infinite loop.